# Update with count from same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table table_1 with a column parent_id with the value of the column id from other records from the same table.
I want to set another column out_degree with the number of records which have this table's id as their parent_id.
I tried this:

```
UPDATE table_1 p1
   SET p1.out_degree = ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                           FROM table_1 p2, 
                                table_1 p1
                          WHERE p2.parent_id = p1.id 
                       GROUP_BY p1.id
                       )
```

But it didn't work. any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE table_1 T1 
  JOIN ( SELECT parent_id,Count(parent_id) as ParentCount
           FROM table_1
       GROUP BY parent_id
       ) T2 ON T1.parent_id=T2.parent_id
   SET T1.out_degree=T2.parentCount
```

See the sample result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b74b8/4).

Comment: Thanks to you for illustrating us with your answer. I didn't knew it was possible to use a `JOIN` in an `UPDATE`. :-)